# Editor needs the permission to edit pages and add widgets to them

Tags: apostrophe-cms

Im trying to create the role of an Editor, with permissions to

- edit piece-pages
- create pieces
- add widgets in piece-pages

The problems i encountered were the following

- Editor could only edit the widgets, that have been added to the piece-page
- Editor couldn't use already uploaded Pictures while editing a piece (Apostrophe freezes and i have to refresh)

I tried to solve those problems with specifying my permissions a little more and it looked like this

```
{
                title: 'Editor',
                permissions: [
                    'edit',
                    'edit-news',
                    'admin-apostrophe-images',
                    'admin-news',
                    'admin-news-pages',
                    'admin-apostrophe-images',
                    'admin-double-image-widget',
                    'admin-triple-image-widget',
                    'admin-apostrophe-files-widget',
                    'admin-kis-widget',
                    'admin-two-column-widget',
                    'admin-expandable-widget',

                ]
            },
```

The entries with the `"admin-` prefix are the widgets, that should be available in the piece-page and
`news`is the piece, which should be editable and creatable by the editor

Since the admin-prefix gives full permission i thought it would be the right thing to do, but it didn't help at all.

Am i missing something or am i using the permissions wrong?

EDIT: The widgets that have been listed in my permission, are the widgets that have been included the `show.html` of the `news-page` I can freely add them to the page while being an admin-user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so i found the Solution myself. The problem was that the permissions i added were not the correct ones. 
I found the "Edit Group" area in the Apostrophe Interface.
There was a list of checkboxes with permission to add to my group named "editor". 
After i selected all the permissions i needed, i logged my current User and copied the permission to paste them in my app.js